# How to merge .csv files to do a matrix

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, merge

I have two different .csv files (a and b), containing several array organized like this :

File a :

```
[a, b, c, d]

[e, f, g, h]

[i, j, k, l]
```

File b :

```
[o, p, q, r]

[s, t, u, v]

[w, x, y, z]
```

I want to merge these to files to get only on file (c), that would look like :

```
[a, b, c, d, o, p, q, r]

[e, f, g, h, s, t, u, v]

[i, j, k, l, w, x, y, z]
```

Any ideas how I could do this? I'm running Python 2.7 (matplotlib, openelectrophy).

Comment: Use pandas DataFrames will get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python's csv reader and writer,
reading from the files `a.csv` and `b.csv`, writing to `c.csv`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

with open('a.csv', 'r') as file_a:
    with open('b.csv', 'r') as file_b:
        with open('c.csv', 'w') as file_c:
            reader_a = csv.reader(file_a, delimiter=',')
            reader_b = csv.reader(file_b, delimiter=',')
            writer_c = csv.writer(file_c)

            for cols_a in reader_a:
                cols_b = reader_b.next()
                writer_c.writerow(cols_a + cols_b)
```

Creates file `c.csv`:

```
a, b, c, d,o, p, q, r
e, f, g, h,s, t, u, v
i, j, k, l,w, x, y, z
```

(I assume that those braces and extra linebreaks in your csv code are just here on stackoverflow and not really part of your csv files? I also assume that a.csv and b.csv have the same length in lines.)

Comment: Really nice answer, it works perfectly ! Thank you user3760780 !